# Downloading images off a website with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to download every image on a website using a node script.

I wrote it and for the most part it seems to be working, however, it's only downloading the first image. It downloads it equal to the number of images on the site.

Here is my code.

```
const http = require('http'),
cheerio = require('cheerio'),
fs = require('fs');
var document = '';
var imageData = '';
http.get('http://www.wikihow.com/Start-a-Blog', function(res){
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        document+=chunk;
    })
res.on('end', function(){
    let $ = cheerio.load(document); 
    var array = [];
    var array = $("img").toArray();
    var data = [];
    array.forEach(function (ele) {
        if (ele.attribs.src !== undefined)
        data.push(ele.attribs.src);
    })
    var counter = 0;
    data.forEach(function (ele) {
        ripImage(ele, counter);
        counter ++;
    })
})
});

function ripImage(ele, counter){

http.get(ele, function(res){
    console.log(res);
    res.setEncoding('binary')
    res.on('data', function(chunk){
        imageData += chunk;
    })
    res.on('end', function(){
        //console.log(ele);
            fs.writeFile("dump/file" + counter + ".jpg", imageData, 'binary', function(err){
            if (err) throw err
            //console.log('File saved.')
        });
    //res.pipe(file);
    })
});
}
```

I think the problem lies somewhere in the ripImage() function. If you guys can see the problem, and help me fix it, that'd be really appreciated.

Thanks guys.

Comment: you could work with async queue, cheerio and request. I don't understand why you use low implementations of http requests. This could be simpler with one queue and one-two functions.

Comment: I'm trying to use as few resources as possible for learning more than anything. I'm still relatively new to Node so I'm just getting a grasp for things.

Answer (score 0):

@Mr.Phoenix is right, the async library is meant for this type of thing. It allows you to iterate over a collection with an asynchronous function, and fire a callback when all of the async functions have completed. Working code:

```
const http = require('http')
const cheerio = require('cheerio')
const fs = require('fs')
const async = require('async')

let document = ''

http.get('http://www.wikihow.com/Start-a-Blog', (res) => {
  res.on('data', (chunk) => {
    document += chunk
  })

  res.on('end', () => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(document)

    const data = $('img')
      .toArray()
      .filter((ele) => ele.attribs.src)
      .map((ele) => ele.attribs.src)

    async.eachOf(data, ripImage, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err
      console.log('all done!')
    })
  })
})

function ripImage (ele, i, callback) {
  http.get(ele, (res) => {
    let imageData = ''

    res.setEncoding('binary')

    res.on('data', (chunk) => {
      imageData += chunk
    })

    res.on('end', () => {
      fs.writeFile('./dump/file' + i + '.jpg', imageData, 'binary', callback)
    })
  })
}
```